# Ember re-render when not in DOM

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-components

I have four components setup from the same model. Depending on the state of the item, it will be shown in one of the four components.

Components are: is-new, is-ready, is-started, is-completed.

On each of these components I have a timestamp, that I would like to update continuously. However Ember breaks with the following error whenever the DOM or state of the models update.

`Something you did caused a view to re-render after it rendered but before it was inserted into the DOM.`

This is an example of one of the components:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'article',

  click: function() {
    this.attrs.action();
  },

  didInsertElement: function() {
    this.updateCreatedAt();
  },

  updateCreatedAt: function() {
    console.log(this.isDestroying, this.isDestroyed);
    if (this.isVisible && !this.isDestroying && !this.isDestroyed) {
      this.rerender();
    }
    Ember.run.later(this, 'updateCreatedAt', 60000);
  }
});
```

Does anyone have any clues on this matter?

Comment: `Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, updateCreatedAt);` In your `didInsertElement` hook

Comment: @Kitler works like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: Np, I ll add it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the `didInsertElement` hook is triggered the template did not necessarily render, you will need to schedule it using [Ember.run.scheduleOnce](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html#method_scheduleOnce):

```
didInsertElement() {
  Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, updateCreatedAt);
}
```